# How to make option text of select menu fit into a div

Tags: html, css

I have a select menu, where the option text is very long, I would like it to fit the width of the div, also I would like to text formatting to show up correctly.

HTML:

```
<div Id"upgrade">
    <select class="option">
       <option value="Opt8">No Package Added</option>
       <option value="31"><strong>Standard Package</strong><br> text sdjhfdkj skdjghkdfjg kdjfghkd;fjgh kjghkdfj kjhgdkfjhg kjdfhkdj</option>
       <option value="40"><strong>fshgf</strong><br>jkdhfgida kjdfipusd sdk;fuh sdfh d;sofih dfhio[ih sd;fihero[</option>


       </select></div>
```

CSS

```
#upgrade select{width:75%; white-space:normal}
.option{width:75%; white-space:nomal ;}
```

The text of the option is just displayed in one line I would like it to look as follows:

**Standard Package**
 text sdjhfdkj skdjghkdfjg kdjfghkd;fjgh kjghkdfj kjhgdkfjhg kjdfhkdj

And then break when it overflows the width of the div and not continue in one line. But still show up the rest of the text in a next line as in normal div

Any help welcome

Comment: You can't put <br> tag in the option, this is invalid. You can use plugin like this http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<div Id"upgrade">` specifically (which causes `#upgrade select` to not match), but also putting HTML in an `option` is not valid either.

Answer (score 0):

You are very limited with the styling you can apply to a select element and its options. You can try a JavaScript based alternative instead, if you want more flexibility:

https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the long option in a div too and then setting overflow and width to auto, but I don't believe that would work to your desired effect. This might need some script!